# Bash: append text to last line of file

Tags: bash, text, append, eof, sh

How can I add a percentage symbol % to the end of the last line in a text file?

I do not want the % to be on a new line, it must be at the end of the last line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
sed '${s/$/%/}' file
```

Comment: The braces are superfluous and actually make it less portable, since then there would need to be a semicolon before the closing brace.. So, `sed '$s/$/%/'` or `sed '${s/$/%/;}'`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when you put a variable like `${x}` in place of `/%`

Comment: My god ! Such perfection. Thanks !

Comment: @Timothy Swan, use string concatenation: `sed '$s/$/'"$x"'/'`

Comment: Question specifies the LAST LINE of the file. The following will work for that:
sed '${s/$/'"${x}"'/;}'

Comment: The answer works for specifically the last line, @user1754036, at least with sed on Ubuntu.

Comment: BTW, if it doesn't work, make sure there is no UNIX newline hidden somewhere.
Open the file in VIM and see if it has "^M" indicated at the end of the line.