# echo to file without new line

Tags: linux, bash

I have a config file generated from a program, and I would like to add some text at the end of the last line of the file.

Example file:

```
ABC123
DFG
```

What I want:

```
ABC123
DFG test
```

When I try echo with `-n` and `-e`, or `printf` I can't achieve this, it's always printing on a new line.

Comment: Is "DFG" the last line, or the last non-empty line (DFG\n)?

Comment: @fedorqui this thread is marked as duplicate, but I feel that answer is not entirely correct, although this particular thread has a `linux` tag, while the other does not and so that means GNU `sed`, which can handle the missing semicolon..

Comment: I am not sure if this is really a dupe. This question specifically asks how to do it with `echo`, and it might be worth to know that a pure `echo` solution is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you always append to the last line!

The real problem is that what *you* consider to be the last line is actually not. If you place a `\n` everywhere where there is a newline character, it becomes apparent:

```
ABC123\n
DFG\n
                 <-- THIS is the last line
```

With `echo` alone, you cannot append where you intend; a solution requires *reading* the file (at least everything beyond the insert position), and writing out again everything beyond the insertion position.

[`sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657860/bash-append-text-to-last-line-of-file) can do something like this.

***Remark*** about the solution proposed by [agilob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22960224/76722):

```
echo "$(cat file.txt)test" > file.txt
```

This is not an in-place insertion; actually it reads the whole file, passes the whole content on the command line to the `echo` tool, and only after that it will completely overwrite your `file.txt`. For large files, this can impose severe problems, depending on your shell.

This is unlike a `sed` solution, which will edit the file while streaming it ("live") and therefore is superiour for large files, also w.r.t. performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with sed:

```
sed '$s/$/ test/' file
```

--
edit: since this thread was marked as duplicate and I feel that answer is not entirely correct, I added some comments there...